# Joomla article permissions, show alternative text for user without access

Tags: joomla

I am trying to get an article to show some text like "You do not have permission to view this article" when a user doesn't have the correct access level.

Currently the article just shows no content if the user doesn't have the right permissions. how would I go about showing content for a user who doesn't have access?

Comment: Check your template to see if it has a messages area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla's normal behaviour for any resource that a user doesn't have viewing permissions for is to display a message. e.g. this is the default message in Joomla 2.5 in the default template:
[image: Joomla 2.5 Default Not Authorised Message - Front End]

and this a Joomla 3.2 example:

[image: Joomla 3.2 Default Not Authorised Message - Front End]

If you're seeing a page with nothing in the content area then (as @Elin suggests) it's likely that your template doesn't have a message block. Specifically your looking for a line like this in you templates `index.php` code:

```
<jdoc:include type="message" />
```

When Joomla renders the page it replaces this `jdoc` tag with any system messages such as the not authorised one.

If you don't like the wording of the message you can over-ride the language key `JERROR_ALERTNOAUTHOR` using the `Extensions->Language Manager->Language Overrides` feature, just remember to select "Site" before creating a new over-ride as this is a front-end message.